# Changing sprite renderer material in gameplay

Tags: unity

I'm having an issue on some android devices with one of my games functions. Its a puzzle game and i assign different materials on the generated images pieces which causes the game to freeze on some devices. The first function to be called which changes the material to an outline one is this

```
 public void StartGame()
    {
        InterchangeRandom(shuffledArray);
        Debug.Log("shuffle");
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            float scaleWidth = 100 * ((float)shuffledArray[i][2]) / ((float)selectedArray[i][2]);
            float scaleHeight = 100 * ((float)shuffledArray[i][3]) / ((float)selectedArray[i][3]);
            spawnedGameObjects[i].transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, 0);

            // Material OutlineMaterial = Resources.Load<Material>("Solid_frame_inside_under");
            spawnedGameObjects[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material = normal;
           //mat.material = normal;

            // Place pieces to the shuffled positions
            float halfWidth = ((float)shuffledArray[i][2]) / ((float)2);
            float halfHeight = ((float)shuffledArray[i][3]) / ((float)2);
            spawnedGameObjects[i].transform.position = new Vector3(shuffledArray[i][0] - 660 + halfWidth, shuffledArray[i][1] - 450 + halfHeight, 0);
            spawnedGameObjects[i].GetComponent<ClickOn>().MoveTo(spawnedGameObjects[i].transform.position);

            isPlaying = true;
        }

    }
```

The normal material is a white outline on all spawned pieces. then on each click i change it again to a red outline with an overlay and on game end i change it back to nothing using sprite default.

I have added the materials in the build settings preloaded assets but that didn't help. i have a count down timer for game start and call that function when timer is 0 but the game stops for a couple of seconds until the materials are swaped in the game objects. Any help would be appreciated. Like if there is a way to preload all of them because this only happens in the first gameplay, once i reload the level nothing freezes anymore.

edit: the way im changing the materials on the other functions is this

For game end:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < selectedArray.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    var mat = spawnedGameObjects[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                    mat.material = finished;
                }
```

for once the pieces are back to their place:

```
 selection = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("puzzle").GetComponent<ClickOn>();
        selection.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material = normal;
```

And in the spawned gameobjects i also change the material based on click using this:

```
 GetComponent<Renderer>().material = array.selected;
```

Comment: If there isn't a better answer then a solution would be to just have a duplicate (inactive) game object with the "normal" material already applied and just switch it out with the original (copying any relevant values) when you want to "change materials". Sort of a pooling system.

Comment: wont that put too much stress in the system? or are you just talking about the initial material setting? like show the ones without the outline first and then deactivate them and show the ones with the outline?

Comment: yeah exactly, just switch gameobjects out with the seperate materials already assigned at start up or at build time. It would avoid making Unity do some potentially complicated material/graphics-pipeline thing it has to do at runtime. (I'm not sure if when you say "freeze" whether you mean an fps drop or a crash)

Comment: Have you considered using the sharedMaterial setter, to ensure you're not accidentally creating copies of materials everywhere?

Comment: well it seems my issue is with the materials themselves. i did an image overlay of the whole image and then hide it to show the pieces with the outlines but as long as the material change is in the function the game freezes for a couple of seconds.